# How to replace default values with database values in a table using ReactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, mongodb, redux

The question is: In mongodb collection, When there are 0 documents inside the "appmovie" array, it should show default values of "appmovie".

When you turn the toggle ON , then its status should be "Watched on 1 August 2021 10:00am" and other's toggle should be OFF and status should be blank. When there is change, the changed values should be fetched from the database and be shown. Other values should be from the default.

**How can I achieve that?**

Let me show my code and explain what I want to do.

Below is the `ReactJs` code. I have a table with only 4 rows and each row has 4 columns: Name, platform, Flag (which is a On Off switch) and Status (which tells when switch is ON-shows date and time of movie watched, when switch is OFF-shows last date and time of movie watched with the current date and time you turned the movie OFF. This gets saved in an array of history in the database).

Initially the collection "appmovie" in mongodb database is empty. Then the values to be shown on the table should be default values as in `const row`. Once the default values is seen on the table, and when a particular movie switch is `ON`, then only that row's values should be fetched from the database and shown on that row, rest 3 rows should only have the default values as `const row`.

The problem I am facing is, when I switch `ON`, it gives success message and entry goes in the database but, it does not reflect in the table. When all the switches are `ON` then it shows the data from the database.

I have no idea how to go about.

Note: All the components needed are being imported. React `reducer` and `action` is being written properly. `appMovieHistory` is an `array` of `objects` with `watchDate` in it.

```
import {getAppMovieData, saveOrUpdateMovie} from "./actions/appMovieAction";
import moment from "moment";
   
const headers = [
  { id: "appMovieName", label: "Movie Name" },
  { id: "platform", label: "Platform" },
  { id: "movieFlag", label: "Movie Flag" },
  {path: "appMovieHistory.watchDate",label: "Status"},
];

const row = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    appMovieName: "Spider Man",
    platform: "A",
    movieFlag: false,
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    appMovieName: "Amazing Spider Man",
    platform: "i",
    movieFlag: false,
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    appMovieName: "Ferdinand",
    platform: "A",
    movieFlag: false,
  },
  {
    _id: 4,
    appMovieName: "Finding Dory",
    platform: "i",
    movieFlag: false,
  },
];


class AppMovie extends Component {
  state = {
    currentDateTime: Date().toLocaleString(),
    modalOpen: false,
    snackOpen: false,
    editMode: false,
    flagToEdit: false,
    data: {},
    movieFlag: false,
    appMovieName: "",
    platform: "",
    _id: "",
    appMovieHistory: [],
  };

  handleModalOpen = (r) => {
    let flag = {
      _id: r._id,
      appMovieName: r.appMovieName,
      platform: r.platform,
      movieFlag: r.movieFlag,
    };
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: true,
      movieFlag: flag.movieFlag,
      appMovieName: flag.appMovieName,
      platform: flag.platform,
    });
  };

  handleModalClose = () => {
    this.setState({ modalOpen: false });
  };

  handleSwitchChangeAppMovieFlag = async (
    id,
    appMovieName,
    platform,
    movieFlag,
    appMovieHistory
  ) => {
    const payload = {
      _id: id,
      appName: appName,
      platform: platform,
      movieFlag: !movieFlag,
      appMovieHistory: appMovieHistory,
    };
    await this.props.saveOrUpdateMovie(payload);
    await this.props.getAppMovieData();
    await this.handleModalClose();
  };

  handleSnackClose = () => {
    this.props.getAppMovieData();
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAppMovieData();
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;   

    if (this.props.appMovie.appMovie.length < 4) {
      return (
        <Container>    
          <TableContainer>
            <Table>
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  {headers.map((headCell) => (
                    <TableCell
                      key={headCell.id}
                      align={"left"}
                    >
                      {headCell.label}
                    </TableCell>
                  ))}
                  <div />
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>

              <TableBody>
                {row.map((r) => (
                  <TableRow key={r._id}>
                    <TableCell align="left">
                      {r.appMovieName}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left">
                      {r.platform}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left">
                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={
                          <Switch
                            checked={r.movieFlag}
                            color="primary"
                            onClick={() => this.handleModalOpen(r)}
                          />
                        }
                        label={r.movieFlag ? "On" : "Off"}
                      />
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left">                          
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>

          <Modal
            open={this.state.modalOpen}
            onClose={this.handleModalClose}
          >
            <Container>
              <Container>
                <Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={8}>
                      {this.state.movieFlag== true
                        ? "Off"
                        : "On"}
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={4}>
                   <CloseIcon onClick={this.handleModalClose}/>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </Container>
              <Container>
                <Grid>
                  {this.state.movieFlag== true
                    ? "TURN OFF?"
                    : "TURN ON?"}
                </Grid>
              </Container>

              <Container>
                <Grid>
                  <Grid></Grid>
                  <Grid>
                    <Button onClick={this.handleModalClose}
                    >
                      Cancel
                    </Button>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid>
                    <Button
                      type="submit"
                      color={
                        this.state.movieFlag == true
                          ? "default"
                          : "primary"
                      }
                      onClick={() =>
                        this.handleSwitchChangeAppMovieFlag(
                          this.state._id,
                          this.state.appMovieName,
                          this.state.platform,
                          this.state.movieFlag,
                          this.state.appMovieHistory
                        )
                      }
                    >
                      {this.state.movieFlag== true
                        ? "Turn off"
                        : "Turn on"}
                    </Button>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </Container>
            </Container>
          </Modal>
        </Container>
      );
    } 


else {
      return (
        <Container>
          <Container>
            <Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Container>

          <TableContainer>      
            <Table>
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  {headers.map((headCell) => (
                    <TableCell
                      key={headCell.id}
                      align={"left"}
                    >
                      {headCell.label}
                    </TableCell>
                  ))}
                  <div />
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>

              <TableBody>
                {this.props.appMovie.appMovie.map((r) => (
                  <TableRow key={r._id}>
                    <TableCell>
                      {r.appMovieName}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left">
                      {r.platform}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left">
                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={
                          <Switch
                            checked={r.movieFlag}
                            color="primary"
                            onClick={() => this.handleModalOpen(r)}
                          />
                        }
                        label={r.movieFlag ? "On" : "Off"}
                      />
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left" >
                      {r.appMovieHistory &&
                      r.appMovieHistory.length > 0 ? (
                        r.movieFlag ? (
                          <Typography>
                            Watched on
                            {moment(
                              r.appMovieHistory [
                                r.appMovieHistory .length - 1
                              ].watchDate
                            ).format(" DD-MMMM-YYYY hh:mm A ")}
                          </Typography>
                        ) : (
                          <Typography >
                            Last Watched from
                            {moment(
                              r.appMovieHistory [
                                r.appMovieHistory .length - 2
                              ].watchDate
                            ).format(" DD-MMMM-YYYY hh:mm A ")}
                            to
                            {moment(
                              r.appMovieHistory [
                                r.appMovieHistory .length - 1
                              ].watchDate
                            ).format(" DD-MMMM-YYYY hh:mm A ")}
                          </Typography>
                        )
                      ) : (
                        "--"
                      )}
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>

          <Modal
            open={this.state.modalOpen}
            onClose={this.handleModalClose}
          >
            <Container>
              <Container>
                <Grid>
                  <Grid >
                      {this.state.movieFlag == true
                        ? "Off "
                        : "On "}
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid}>
                      <CloseIcon
                        onClick={this.handleModalClose}
                      />
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </Container>
              <Container>
                <Grid>
                  {this.state.movieFlag == true
                    ? "TURN OFF movie?"
                    : "TURN ON movie"}
                </Grid>
              </Container>

              <Container>
                <Grid>
                  <Grid></Grid>
                  <Grid>
                    <Button
                      onClick={this.handleModalClose}
                    >
                      Cancel
                    </Button>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid>
                    <Button
                      color={
                        this.state.movieFlag == true
                          ? "default"
                          : "primary"
                      }
                      onClick={() =>
                        this.handleSwitchChangeAppMovieFlag(
                          this.state._id,
                          this.state.appMovieName,
                          this.state.platform,
                          this.state.movieFlag,
                          this.state.appMovieHistory 
                        )
                      }
                    >
                      {this.state.movieFlag == true
                        ? "Turn off"
                        : "Turn on"}
                    </Button>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </Container>
            </Container>
          </Modal>
        </Container>
      );
    }
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {      
    appMovie: state.appMovie,
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getAppMovieData,
  saveOrUpdateMovie,
})(AppMovie);
```

Everything else works, But only the change cannot be seen when it is `switched ON` or `switched OFF`. I really need help with this.
Please help.
Thank you!